# How to get the title of WP Job Manager?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create a list of a latest job that created in WP Job Manager. But I don't know how to get the job title (class or function) to call in WP Job Manager.

Below is the code for my Hirings Post. But the currently display here is the wordpress post title.

```html
<ul id="hiring-title">
  <span class="line"></span>
  <h4>HIRINGS</h4>

<!-- // Define our WP Query Parameters -->
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=4' ); ?>
     
<!-- // Start our WP Query -->
<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
     
<!-- // Display the Post Title with Hyperlink -->
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
     
<!-- // Repeat the process and reset once it hits the limit -->
<?php 
  endwhile;
   wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ul id="hiring-title">
    <span class="line"></span>
    <h4>HIRINGS</h4>

    <?php
    // Get jobs
    $jobs = get_job_listings();

    // Jobs found, list them
    if ( $jobs->have_posts() ) {

        while ( $jobs->have_posts() ) : $jobs->the_post();
        ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_job_permalink() ?>"><?php wpjm_the_job_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php
        endwhile;

    } // No jobs available / found
    else {
        ?>
        <li>No jobs available.</li>
        <?php
    }

    // Restore original post object
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</ul>
```

For more details, please check [WP Job Manager's documentation](https://wpjobmanager.com/documentation/).

Answer (score 0):

Additional information:

My problem was that I wanted to assign the title to a variable. However, the `wpjm_the_job_title` function outputs the title directly. After a long research I found out that all functions of WPJobManager are structured according to the following pattern:

Output Title:

```
wpjm_the_job_title()
```

Return Title:

```
wpjm_get_the_job_title()
```